# Printing elements of StdObject Array PHP

Tags: php, twitter

This is a tricky one (for me). I have an Array of data returned from a Twitter API call in an Array. I'm iterating the "Top 10 Trending" however cannot print the individual elements i.e. name, Below is the code I am using to get as far as I can:

```
  $twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey,$consumerSecret,$oAuthToken,$oAuthSecret);

  $locale = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=560472');


  foreach($locale as $local)
  {
    print_r($local->trends);
  }
```

This results in the below:

[image: Result of Query]

However I cannot access the individual elements through the Array at the top. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance, Niall

Comment: Can you share your code which isn't working for the array access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tweets = $local->trends;

echo $tweets[1]->name;
```

Or you can use foreach :

```
foreach ($local->trends as $trend)
{
    echo $trend->name;
}
```

Comment: I just tweaked your code a bit             foreach($locale as $local)
    {
      echo "Number 1 Trending is: ".$local->trends[0]->name."<br />";
      echo "Number 2 Trending is: ".$local->trends[1]->name."<br />";
      echo "Number 3 Trending is: ".$local->trends[2]->name."<br />";
      echo "Number 4 Trending is: ".$local->trends[3]->name."<br />";
      //print_r($local->trends);
    }

Comment: Working though! Thanks!!